# LibreOffice 5.1 Writer: insert script

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

In the previous versions of LibreOffice, one could insert script into an odt from "insert" menu.

According to official answer this feature was removed:
https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/67576/menu-insert-script-removed/

How am I then supposed to insert script? What is "Writer HTML", which this answer is suggesting? I can't find a word about it anywhere else.

Am I forced to install earlier versions of LibreOffice just for this feature if I want to avoid digging through massive XMLs?

Also, can anyone explain the reason of that move (removing existing, convenient feature from the product)?

Comment: Why do you want to insert script into an .odt file?  Are you making a web page, or perhaps creating a macro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create an HTML document in Writer (meant by "Writer HTML"), go to `File -> New -> HTML Document`, and then it will be possible to insert a script.  Or, it sounds like you may want `File -> New -> XML Form Document` instead.

It looks to me like `Insert -> Script` is useful only for adding Javascript or similar to a document, which seems appropriate for an HTML document or forms.  So the new change makes sense to me.

To write a Javascript **macro**, put the code in a text file under the LibreOffice user directory, as described [here](https://www.openoffice.org/framework/scripting/release-0.2/javascript-devguide.html).

**EDIT**:

From the comment below, it sounds like you are [inserting a directive](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/?q=node/25) for use with JODReports.  Could you do the following instead:

> Insert a FreeMarker directive in OpenOffice.org Writer from the menu Insert / > Fields / Other... (or just press Ctrl+F2), then click on the Functions tab and > select Input field. Change the field Reference to JOOScript and in the > following field Content enter the directive (e.g. "[#assign title='Mr.']").

Note: Apache OpenOffice still has `Insert -> Script`.

Comment: Well, my firm uses hundreds of .odt files with JOOScripts serving as templates. Inserting script in standard editor was very convenient, so ultimately I ended up installing earlier version of LibreOffice. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: Ow, that is what I seek. Looks like we were doing it the wrong way then all the time, mixing script and input fields. This exhausts the question, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The script functionnality is still there.  It's just not in the default menus.  Go to 
[Scripting LibreOffice](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Scripting) for adding it back to the Insert menu items.

Here is one way to add it back (done with Version: 5.3.2.2) :

1. Choose **Tools - Customize**, and click the **Menus** tab.
2. In **LibreOffice Writer Menus**, scroll down to Insert.
3. In **Menu Content - Entries**, scroll down to any item after which you want the Script item to appear.
4. Click **Add Commands**.
5. In the **Category** list box, choose All catgories.
6. In the **Commands** list box, scroll down to Script
7. Click **Add** to create a new menu item. The new menu entry appears in the **Entries** list box.
8. Click **OK** and you are ready to insert a new script object anywhere.